# Regex to replace "t" with "T" only if succeeded by "a","o","u" with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

> In Javascript I want to replace "t" with "T" but only if the character after the "t" is succeeded by "a","o","u". Eg: String: tatotu, Target String: TaToTu
>   I couldn't find the Regex.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
  
  var text = $(this).val();
  text = text.replace("t, (\\a|\\o|\\u)","T");
  $("#ta_1").val(text);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
  
   <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
    
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: It’s `/t(?=a|o|u)/`. Why would it be the string `"t, (\\a|\\o|\\u)"` which contains literal commas, literal spaces, literal parentheses and literal backslashes?

Comment: @Xufox not working :/

Comment: Did you put it in string quotes again? Don’t do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an actual regular expression with lookaheads.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

    var text = $(this).val();
    text = text.replace(/t(?=a|o|u)/g, "T");
    $("#ta_1").val(text);

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How would be the regex of its inverse sir ? eg: aToTuT aT oT

Comment: @pinug That would either necessitate lookbehinds (which JavaScript doesn’t have, unfortunately), or you just reverse the regex and use a normal capturing group: `text = text.replace(/(a|o|u)t/g, "$1T");` or — if you plan to add more vowels or other letters — in a more compact way: `text = text.replace(/([aou])t/g, "$1T");`.

Comment: Just here to obsolete part of my previous comment: Lookbehind assertions will land in the upcoming ECMAScript 2018 spec.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var map={"ta":"Ta", "to": "To", "tu": "Tu"}; 
    var regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(map).join("|"), "g"); 
    var output = "tatotu".replace(regex, function(matched){return map[matched]});
alert(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `replace` callback:

```
...
text = text.replace(/(t)(a|o|u)/gi, function(m, p1, p2) { 
    return p1.toUpperCase() + p2; 
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex like this would be suffice.

**Regex:** `t(a|o|u)`

**Replace with:** `T$1` or `T\1`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA7cC8/1)**

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "tatatou";
var result = str.replace(/t([aou])/g, "T$1");
```